# How to handle tags which have changed meaning?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I was wondering how to handle tags which have accidentally changed meaning. For example [graphdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphdb) refers to a vendor specific implementation of a graph database. However, when investigating its uses I have noticed that most people use the tag in the same way they use [graph-databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-databases), i.e. they use it when referring to Generic Graph Databases, not this specific vendor.

What would be the best course of action?

1. Rename the tag to be less ambiguous?
2. Edit the description of the tag to satisfy its new meaning?
3. Somehow merge the tags?

Comment: Renaming the tag could frustrate people, because they're already use to it. Maybe try and edit the description or add few more synonym tags. If there are a lot of people using it... best course of action would be A/B testing.

Comment: It's a small community. 36 questions roughly. What is A/B Testing ? I am leaning toward editing the tag to be similar to [graph-databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-databases) and then specify they are synonyms.

Comment: More on what [A/B testing means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) ... Basically just try 2. and 3. and see what happens :)

Comment: It is not exactly uncommon that people tag "what they use" even if it is not really relevant to the question asked. For example people like to tag the IDE they're using while the question is just about a programming language. The course of action to take is to edit the tags so they are relevant.

Comment: I tend to prefer Debian way: neither get the name, both use similar but not the same name.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This tag currently has only 37 questions. I don't think that the situation which you describe, i.e. people using it when they mean to use [graph-databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-databases) happens very often. When you see that someone is misusing this tag, just edit it out.

Therefore, I don't think that renaming this tag is necessary. Also, the tag excerpt already contains information that it shouldn't be used for questions about graph databases in general:

> For questions that are about graph databases in general (or about other graph database products), use [graph-databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-databases) instead.

I completely disagree with merging these tags, because they refer to different things.

Comment: That seems to be fair. Is it worth retroactively editing out the misuses then ?

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira Yes.